# Javascript - LinkedIn API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve user fields using the LinkedIn API, in JavaScript.

I wish to pass this information as variables to another page using AJAX.

The code works fine, but a problem occurs when a user has an empty field.

For example, if I go to my LinkedIn Profile and delete my current job, the code stops working and no variables are passed because this field - `positions.values[0].title` is empty.

Removing this entire line `document.getElementById("imgTitle").src = member.positions.values[0].title;` will get it working again.

My question is how do I deal with the empty fields, and pass these variables as either `""` or `null` using AJAX?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key:   [apikey]
        onLoad:    onLinkedInLoad
        authorize: true
        lang:      [LANG_LOCALE]
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function onLinkedInLoad() {

            IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
        }
        function onLinkedInAuth() {
            IN.API.Profile("me")
                    .fields(
                            "firstName", 
                            "lastName", 
                            "industry", 
                            "location:(name)",
                            "picture-url", 
                            "headline", 
                            "summary", 
                            "num-connections", 
                            "public-profile-url", 
                            "distance", 
                            "positions", 
                            "email-address", 
                            "educations", 
                            "date-of-birth"
                    )
                    .result(displayProfiles)
                    .error(displayProfilesErrors);
        }

        function displayProfiles(profiles) {
            member = profiles.values[0];
            alert(JSON.stringify(member));

            document.getElementById("lblName").innerHTML = member.firstName + " " + member.lastName + "<br/> Location is " + member.location.name;
            document.getElementById("imgProfile").src = member.pictureUrl;
            document.getElementById("imgTitle").src = member.positions.values[0].title;
            document.getElementById("lblProfile").innerHTML = member.publicProfileUrl;
            document.getElementById("lblEmail").innerHTML = member.emailAddress;


            var firstName = member.firstName;
            var emailAddress = member.emailAddress;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "heya.php",
                data: {firstname: firstName, email: emailAddress},
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });


        }
        function displayProfilesErrors(error) {
            profilesDiv = document.getElementById("profiles");
            profilesDiv.innerHTML = error.message;
            console.log(error);
        }


    </script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="in/Login">
</script>
<br/>
<b>Get Linkedin LoggedIn User Details</b>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><label id="lblName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><label id="lblEmail"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Profile Url:</td>
        <td><label id="lblProfile"/></td>
        <td>Title:</td>
        <td><label id="lblTitle"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Profile Image:</td>
        <td><img id="imgProfile"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="profiles">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a better way but I used the Lodash library and got around my problem like so:

```
    if(_.has(profile, 'positions.values[0].title') == true){
    var title = profile.positions.values[0].title;
    }else{
    var title = "";
    }
```